# Can't get my secondary monitor to power on in X11

Tags: xorg, xrandr, multi-monitor

I have an ATI HD5770, connected to 2 monitors(DVI and DisplayPort).
When booting up ArchLinux the TTY display is duplicated between the two monitors as excepted, but when starting the X server(Awesome WM) I'm stuck with only one monitor, while the other one is going to power save mode(black screen).
xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 8192 x 8192
DisplayPort-0 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00  
   720x400       70.08
```

The resolutions on the DisplayPort are also incorrect.
I've tried so many xrandr command combinations, nothing changed the fact that the DisplayPort connected monitor is inactive.
It's probably worth mentioning that I'm using xf86-video-ati and on Windows(dual boot) I've got no problem with the monitors.
Before that I've also needed to disable Fast Boot from the UEFI configuration tool to be able to actually see the TTY on both monitors.

Answer (score 1):

Installing fglrx(catalyst-total from the AUR) fixed the problem, probably the xf86 driver had some problems with the graphic card DisplayPort.